# JSON data for OpenWeatherMap API is nil when I run the app, but works on the web page

Tags: json, swift, nsurlsession

For some reason the data parameter in this chunk of code:

```
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                if let main = json["main"] as? NSDictionary {
                    if let temp = main["temp"] as? Double {
                        self.temperature = String(format: "%.1f", temp);
                        print(self.temperature);
                    }
                }
            } catch (let error as NSError) {
                print(error);
            }
        });
    });
```

is always nil.

I've made sure the url is correct by copying and pasting it into Safari, and when I go on the website, the data is on the page.

Is there anything I have to fix?

Btw, here's the code that calls this part:

```
if (coordinate != nil) {
    info.getWeatherData("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(coordinate!.latitude)&lon=\(coordinate!.longitude)&APPID={sry, its a secret}");
    print("api
```

Comment: What does the error parameter passed in the block say?

Comment: This code works, I've just tested in a Playground. Your issue is from something else. Are you sure you're not trying to access `self.temperature` before the API response has been received, for example? And yes, show the error if there's one.

Comment: Make sure you set arbritary loads to true in your info.plist or add the thrusted domain to the list or use https

Comment: Make sure you are including the url scheme when constructing your url

Comment: Have you called resume() ?

Comment: Sorry to trouble you guys, but I just figured it out today morning. Apparently the problem was that I didn't add "http://" in the url, so it didn't get the data. But thanks for your help. I really appreciate the thought.